# kivy change attributes of a class using code and not the kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

To change an attribute of a class, say `font_size` of the Label class, I can do add this in the kv file:

```
<Label>
    font_size: "15sp"
```

How do I access the `font_size` attribute via code?

Comment: Have a look at [ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).

Comment: I know about these and they work perfectly for widgets. however, this is not widget by a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague... in what context do you want to access the attribute? If it is at the instantiation then you could do this ...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='hello world', 
font_size= '70sp')
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

But if you want to access the font size of a label that is created in kV... Probably best to assign the label a NumericProperty as font size in the KV file and then change the NumericProperty as needed...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import  NumericProperty

class TestApp(App):
    FontSize = NumericProperty(50)

    def ChangeFont(self):
        self.FontSize +=10
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   TestApp().run()
```

KV...

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        on_press: app.ChangeFont()
    
    Label:
        text: 'Hello'
        font_size: app.FontSize
```

And if you want to access a specific label widget you can make the label a class attribute and then modify it's text directly, if you had many labels you could add each to a list, assign the list as a class attribute and loop over the list changing each label.font_size, the example here only has one label...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyButton(Button):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    L = Label(text = 'hello', font_size = 20)

    def ChangeFont(self):
        self.L.font_size +=10
    
    def build(self):
        B = BoxLayout()
        B.add_widget(MyButton())
        B.add_widget(self.L)
        return B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

KV...

```
<MyButton>:
    text: 'press me'
    on_press: app.ChangeFont()
```

Answer (score -2):

As John said in the comment, use ids to identify your label.

kv file

```
<MyBoxLayout>

    Label:
        id: mylabel
        font_size: '15dp'


    Button:
        on_release: root.change_font_size()
```

python file

```
class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
   def change_font_size(self):
       self.ids.mylabel.font_size = '12dp'
```

Obviously you can do more with it than just change the size once, but thats the basic idea.